# How to change default null sorting behavior from PostgreSQL in the Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

PostgreSQL by default considers NULL values as the highest, and thus sorts them first for descending queries and last for ascending ones.

You can modify this behaviour per query or at index creation by specifying 'NULLS LAST' or 'NULLS FIRST'.

How can I use this in conjunction with the Django ORM, without needing to use raw queries?
I.e. when I add to my query_set something like `qs.order_by("-publish_start")`, how can I specify sorting for nulls? Or, as an alternative, upon field/index declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out a way that accommodates DB engines that work either way (null as highest or lowest value) by using `extra`, making the null check a boolean, and when sorting booleans `false < true` seems to be universal:

```
qs = qs.extra(select={'null_start': "publish_start is null"},
              order_by=['null_start', '-publish_start'])
```

Comment: It's worth stating (because I'm slow and it took me a while to figure out) that if you want the results to be with NULL values first, and then `publish_start` ordered ASCending, you need to reverse the order_by statement: `['-null_start', 'publish_start']`.

Comment: @blueyed yes that is what 4-year old answers in stack overflow have. They grow obsolete. No need to downvote for that...