# Default ordering of model by date with nulls coming first

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, you can define the [default ordering of models with the `ordering` meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering).

If your model is:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

We can fix the ordering of the model, like so:

```
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-end_date','-start_date']
```

Which will put events with the most recent end dates first, and in the case of a tie sort by events with the most recent start date.

However, some events may still be happening, hence a nullable `end_date`. These are the mostest recent events in the system, yet these are being ordered *after* everything else.

**In Django, how can I specify an `ordering` on a date field such that it is descending, but with `null` fields coming first?**

If that's not possible, how can I write the query for the field to get the same effect?

Comment: Which database backend is this for?

Comment: I'd prefer a database independent solution, at the moment its SQLite but may move to Postgres in the future.

Comment: I believe Postgres sorts NULLS first for descending order. The behaviour is a bit different, so you see why I asked. Unfortunately, there is no easy built in trick for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624490/how-to-change-default-null-sorting-behavior-from-postgresql-in-the-django-orm

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that question, and thought that using the `extra` queryset might work, but I'd like to embed it in the default ordering. Thanks though :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17077587/3033586

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late for the party but I've just had this exactly same question and the solution is to use [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/) as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#ordering) like so:

```
ordering = (F("end_date").desc(nulls_first=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked around Django's DB code, it looks Django doesn't provide any hook to customize the processing of 'ordering' meta option, all it does is to generate the `ORDER BY` part of SQL with `ordering` you provided. And I am not aware if any DB allow users to customize comparison function for a particular data type.

Failing that, I see a few alternatives in solving your problem:

1. Drop the ordering option, get the unsorted events and sort in python.
2. Get the events with 2 queries. Get the unfinished events (end_time=NULL), and finished events (end_time!=NULL), this makes sense if   business logic may require the separation of the 2 groups.
3. If the ordering has to happen in DB. Add a default value to end_date, like "2099-01-01", which guarantees the correct ordering.